# Can associations in gorm go both ways?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Can I make associations in gorm go both ways?

i.e.

```
type Store struct {
   ID int
   Products []Product
}

type Product struct {
   ID int
   StoreID int
   Store Store
}
```

So a Store has many Products, and a Product belongs to a Store.

Is this correct?